# How to merge array of objects in single array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

[image]I am new in `JavasSript`.

```
[Array[1], Array[2], Array[0], Array[4], Array[2], Array[8], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1]]
```

I have this array of objects. I want to combine all array objects to single array of objects.

How can i do this?

Comment: *Array of Objects* - I don't see any objects in your code. Can you show the actual input structure?

Comment: this above array contains objects with property called ID.Earch aaray of object has multiple IDs.i want to merge that IDs in single aaray of objects.

Comment: you still haven't shown your input structure

Comment: Please see the above images.

Comment: the majority of the answers presented here should solve your problem. Use one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Concat) on your array of arrays

```js
var arrOfArrays = [["a","b"],["C","D"]];
var flattened = arrOfArrays.reduce(function(p,c){
    return p.concat(c);
});
console.log(flattened);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat and reduce

```js
let list = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]
];

const concat = (x,y) => x.concat(y);

let result = list.reduce(concat, []);

console.log(result);
// [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray = [[1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4]];
var result = [].concat.apply([], myArray);
console.log(result);    // 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4
```